# Reading results from a Neo4j query using C# driver

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have been successful in creating a new Node in my local Neo4j graph from c#.  Now I am trying to determine if the user exists in the graph before I create a new node for the user.  Here is my code:

```
using Neo4j.Driver.V1;     
readonly string uri = "bolt://localhost:7687";
    readonly string user = "user";
    readonly string password = "password";

    _driver = GraphDatabase.Driver(uri, AuthTokens.Basic(user, password));
    private bool checkForUser(string userId)
        {
            bool userFound = false;

            using (var session = _driver.Session())
            {
                var checkUser = session.WriteTransaction(userCheckResults =>
                {
                    var checkUserResult = userCheckResults.Run("MATCH (a:User {UserId: '" + userId + "'}) RETURN a");
//alternate method var checkUserResult = userCheckResults.Run("MATCH (a:User {UserId: $UserId}) RETURN a", new { userId });
                    if (checkUserResult.Keys.Count > 0)
                    {
                        userFound = true;
                    }
                    return checkUserResult;
//also tried this line here to-- return createUserResult.Single();[0].As<string>()
                });
            }
            return userFound;
        }
```

I have tried using the keys as you can see, but this isn't working like expected.  All I am trying to go is get count to see if this node exists or not.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use Cypher [merge](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#query-merge-node-derived) instead of match and check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try having Cypher do the existence check, and return a boolean result:

```
MATCH (a:User {UserId: $UserId}) 
RETURN count(a) > 0 as exists
```

I think checking keys isn't the right approach here, as the keys aren't the number of results, but the variables returned (such as `a` in your query, and `exists` in mine), and those should be constant no matter if you have 0 results or many.

Here's the [IStatementResult](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/dotnet-driver/1.7/html/1ddb9dbe-f40f-26a3-e6f0-7be417980044.htm) interface for reference on what methods you can use to consume the result.

As Guy Coder commented above, you might also consider using MERGE if your intent is to create a new node if one doesn't exist (or otherwise use the existing node).

Comment: Here is what I used to get the results back:
IStatementResult result = tx.Run(@"MATCH (a:User) where a.UserId = '" + userId + "'RETURN a.UserId as UserId");
 List<string> people = result.Select(record => record["UserId"].As<string>()).ToList();